# What's __name__ in the __init__.py?

Tags: python, package, environment-variables, python-import, init

I feel like I have a good grasp of what the `__name__` environment variable is in python in general. However, when I print out the `__name__` variable from an __init__.py it prints out the name of the directory it's in (aka the package name). How does `__name__` get defined in the init file?

Also, does each python file have its own local `__name__` variable? because it's constantly changing between files... (maybe I don't understand `__name__` as well as I thought I did)

---

EDIT: I really don't think this question is the same as the `__name__` equals `__main__` question. I understand what `__name__` equals in most python files. I'm just still confused on what it's value is in the `__init__` files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`__name__` is a "magic" variable within Python's module system. It's simply the module name, or what you import something as. For example, `/radical/__init__.py` would mean that one could do the following

```
import radical
```

The `__init__.py` is how you indicate to Python that you want a folder treated as a module. This allows module hierarchies to be built from multiple files, rather than one giant file. Take for example this piece of code: `/radical/utils.py`

```
import utils from radical
```

Without the `__init__.py` Python treats it as an ordinary folder and so it won't have a module name.

If you run a script directly, `__name__` is loaded as the `__main__` module, which is why `if __name__ == '__main__'` checks that you're running the file instead of importing it.